# Is this statement of P = NP in Agda correct?

Tags: complexity-theory, type-theory, p-vs-np, dependent-types, agda

Looking for a self-contained statement of P = NP in type theory, I stumbled upon this [short Agda formalization](https://pastebin.com/nCE92XUd) (a cleaned up version is reproduced below).

The statement here does seem to express the problem correctly but I'm not entirely sure as the code is not well-commented. So my question is: is this an accurate statement of P = NP and if not how would one fix it?

````
open import Data.Nat                              using    (ℕ; suc; zero; _+_; _*_; _≤_; _^_)
open import Data.Bool                             using    (Bool; true; false; if_then_else_; _∨_)
open import Data.List                             using    (List; _∷_; []; length)
open import Data.Vec                              using    (Vec; _∷_; [])
open import Data.Product                          using    (Σ-syntax; _,_)
open import Data.Sum                              using    (_⊎_; inj₁; inj₂)
open import Data.Empty                            using    (⊥)
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using    (_≡_; refl)

iterate : {A : Set} → ℕ → A → (A → A) → A
iterate zero    z s = z
iterate (suc n) z s = s (iterate n z s)

is-poly : (ℕ → ℕ) → Set
is-poly f = Σ[ m ∈ ℕ ] ((n : ℕ) → f n ≤ 2 ^ m)

is-inj₂ : {A B : Set} → A ⊎ B → Bool
is-inj₂ (inj₁  _) = false
is-inj₂ (inj₂ _) = true

data fn : ℕ → Set where
    fz : {n : ℕ} → fn (suc n)
    fs : {n : ℕ} → fn n → fn (suc n)

ref : {A : Set} {n : ℕ} → fn n → Vec A n → A
ref fz (a ∷ _) = a
ref (fs m) (_ ∷ rest) = ref m rest

subs : {A : Set} {n : ℕ} → fn n → A → Vec A n → Vec A n
subs fz a (_ ∷ rest) = a ∷ rest
subs (fs m) a (b ∷ rest) = b ∷ subs m a rest

replicate : {A : Set} → (n : ℕ) → A → Vec A n
replicate zero a = []
replicate (suc n) a = a ∷ replicate n a

data command (stacks : ℕ) (states : ℕ) : Set where
  push   : fn stacks → Bool → fn states → command stacks states
  pop    : fn stacks → fn states → fn states → fn states
         → command stacks states
  return : Bool → command stacks states

record machine : Set where
  field
    stacks : ℕ
    states : ℕ
    commands : Vec (command stacks states) states
    initial-command : fn states

command-mach : machine → Set
command-mach m = command (machine.stacks m) (machine.states m)

record state (m : machine) : Set where
  constructor mkState
  field
    stacks : Vec (List Bool) (machine.stacks m)
    current : fn (machine.states m)

step : (m : machine) → state m → (state m) ⊎ Bool
exec : {m : machine} → command-mach m → state m → (state m) ⊎ Bool

step m s = exec (ref (state.current s) (machine.commands m)) s
exec (return b) _ = inj₂ b
exec (push i b c) s =
  let
    prev-stack : List Bool
    prev-stack = ref i (state.stacks s)
  in
    inj₁ (mkState (subs i (b ∷ prev-stack) (state.stacks s)) c)

exec (pop i ct cf ce) s with ref i (state.stacks s)
... | []           = inj₁ (mkState (state.stacks s) ce)
... | true  ∷ rest = inj₁ (mkState (subs i rest (state.stacks s)) ct)
... | false ∷ rest = inj₁ (mkState (subs i rest (state.stacks s)) cf)

step-or-halted : (m : machine) → (state m) ⊎ Bool → (state m) ⊎ Bool
step-or-halted m (inj₂ b) = inj₂ b
step-or-halted m (inj₁ s) = step m s

nsteps : {m : machine} → ℕ → state m → (state m) ⊎ Bool
nsteps {m} n s = iterate n (inj₁ s) (step-or-halted m)

initial-state : (m : machine) → List Bool → state m
initial-state m l =
  mkState (replicate (machine.stacks m) l) (machine.initial-command m)

record poly-time-machine : Set where
  inductive
  field
    m : machine
    runtime : ℕ → ℕ
    poly : is-poly runtime
    is-runtime : (l : List Bool)
               → (is-inj₂ (nsteps (runtime (length l)) (initial-state m l))) ≡ true

get-inj₂ : {A B : Set} → (e : A ⊎ B) → is-inj₂ e ≡ true → B
get-inj₂ (inj₁ x) ()
get-inj₂ (inj₂ x) _ = x

run-poly-time-machine : poly-time-machine → List Bool → Bool
run-poly-time-machine m inp = get-inj₂ _ (poly-time-machine.is-runtime m inp)

np-machine : Set
np-machine = poly-time-machine

search : ℕ → poly-time-machine → List Bool → Bool
search zero    m inp = run-poly-time-machine m inp
search (suc n) m inp = search n m (false ∷ inp) ∨ search n m (true ∷ inp)

run-np-machine : np-machine → List Bool → Bool
run-np-machine m inp = search (length inp) m inp

P=NP : Set
P=NP =
  (m-np : np-machine) →
    Σ[ m-p ∈ poly-time-machine ]
      (((inp : List Bool) → run-poly-time-machine m-p inp ≡ run-np-machine m-np inp))
```
````

Answer (score 5):

The definition is not correct. It states that a machine is polynomial time (the field `poly` in `poly-time-machine`) when its running time is below the exponential function $n \mapsto 2^n$ (the definition `is-poly`). This would allow, for example, a running time $n \mapsto 1.5^n$, which isn not poly-time according to the accepted definition.

Comment: So would it suffice to fix `is-poly` to look like `is-poly f = Σ[ m ∈ ℕ ] f ∈ (λ x → x ^ m)` where `f ∈ g = Σ[ c ∈ ℕ ] Σ[ x₀ ∈ ℕ ] ((x : ℕ) → x₀ ≤ x → f x ≤ c * g x)`? Would this then be a correct statement of P = NP?